# How can I generate all possible divisor products for a number?

Tags: python, algorithm, python-3.x, primes, prime-factoring

I'm struggling to implement an algorithm which would give me possible products for a number. For example, for `N=24` these are:

```
24*1, 12*2, 8*3, 6*4, 4*3*2, 3*2*2*2
```

I've implemented a function which calculates the prime factors for a given number with their powers (e.g. `2^3` and `3^1` for `N=24`). But I can't figure out how to get the divisor combinations from the prime factors.

EDIT: Here's what I've tried:

```
def divisors(factors): # prime factors, e.g. [2,2,2,3] for 24
    yield list(factors)

    d = factors.pop()

    for i in range(len(factors)):
        m = [d*factors[i]] + factors[:i] + factors[i+1:]
        yield from divisors(m)
```

Comment: Show us the Python code you have tried.

Comment: It's always important to tell people [what you have tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com/), including snippets of any failed attempts so that they can understand what avenues you have missed. It's important because it motivates people to answer and it's important because it makes it *easier* to give high quality, relevant answers. With the current state of the question, this hasn't been achieved. If you edit the question, it's possible that the question can be prevented from being closed and the quantity, quality and clarity of answers you get will improve as well.

Comment: Note that this is actually a partitioning question: you want to select, in turn, all possible unique combinations of primes to split the set into, and take the product. Hopefully that helps the search.

Comment: I hope you don't have to do this for big numbers, because the number of products grows really fast with the sum of the exponents of the primes in the factorization.

Comment: Are you sure you need to list the products, not just count how many there are?

Comment: If you're after more sophisticated algorithms, see https://oeis.org/A001055 for links to the literature.

Comment: I've added a solution based on the prime factorization.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't say what size numbers you need this to work for, or whether speed is a concern, but here's a very simple unoptimized solution that should work just fine for small inputs (`n` smaller than `10**7`, say).

```
def products(n, min_divisor=2):
    """Generate expressions of n as a product of ints >= min_divisor."""
    if n == 1:
        yield []
    for divisor in range(min_divisor, n+1):
        if n % divisor == 0:
            for product in products(n // divisor, divisor):
                yield product + [divisor]
```

To explain the code, think about how you might do this methodically by hand.  You could start with the products that contain a `2`.  If `n` is odd, there aren't any.  If `n` is even, then we can do a simple recursion: find all possible decompositions of `n // 2`, and then output `decomposition * 2` for each one.  Once we've exhausted all the products containing a `2`, we move on to products involving a `3`.  But here there's an additional complication: in the first step, we've already found all products involving a `2`, so to avoid repeated solutions, we want to restrict to products in which *every* divisor is at least `3`.  So our recursive call needs to keep track of the minimum permitted divisor, `min_divisor` above.  Finally, we need a base case: `1` is expressible as the empty product.

And here's the output for `n=24`, including the `6*2*2` case that you missed:

```
>>> for product in products(24):
...     print('*'.join(map(str, product)))
... 
3*2*2*2
6*2*2
4*3*2
12*2
8*3
6*4
24
```

This is less than satisfying, though: as other commenters have pointed out, it should be possible to compute the multiplicative partitions of `n` from the prime factorisation, and even just from the list of exponents in the prime factorisation, using the primes only when it's necessary to reconstruct the factors.  Here's a variant of the above that works with an existing prime factorisation.  There's still plenty of scope for efficiency improvements: in particular, the `itertools.product` call and subsequent filtering to ignore everything lexicographically smaller than `min_exponents` should be replaced with a custom iterator that *starts* from `min_exponents`.  But this should serve as a starting point.

```
import itertools

def exponent_partitions(exponents, min_exponents):
    """Generate all vector partitions of 'exponents', each of whose
    entries is lexicographically at least 'min_exponents'."""
    if all(exponent == 0 for exponent in exponents):
        yield []
    else:
        for vector in itertools.product(*(range(v+1) for v in exponents)):
            if vector >= min_exponents:
                remainder = tuple(x - y for x, y in zip(exponents, vector))
                for partition in exponent_partitions(remainder, vector):
                    yield partition + [vector]


def divisor_from_exponents(primes, exponent_vector):
    """Reconstruct divisor from the list of exponents."""
    divisor = 1
    for p, e in zip(primes, exponent_vector):
        divisor *= p**e
    return divisor


def multiplicative_partitions(primes, exponents):
    """Generate all multiplication partitions of
    product(p**e for p, e in zip(primes, exponents))"""
    if len(exponents) == 0:
        # Corner case for partitions of 1.
        yield []
    else:
        initial_vector = (0,) * (len(exponents) - 1) + (1,)
        for partition in exponent_partitions(exponents, initial_vector):
            yield [divisor_from_exponents(primes, vector) for vector in partition]
```

And the output for `24`, again:  we're writing `24` as `2**3 * 3**1`, so the tuple of primes is `(2, 3)` and the corresponding tuple of exponents is `(3, 1)`.

```
>>> for product in multiplicative_partitions((2, 3), (3, 1)):
...     print('*'.join(map(str, product)))
... 
2*2*2*3
4*2*3
8*3
6*2*2
12*2
4*6
24
```

There's plenty of literature on generating and counting the multiplicative partitions of an integer.  See for example the links from [OEIS A001055](https://oeis.org/A001055), and the [SAGE functions](http://www.sagemath.org/doc/reference/combinat/sage/combinat/vector_partition.html) for computing vector partitions.

Comment: ... and now that I've found the source for SAGE's `VectorPartitions`, I'm a bit disturbed by how close my code is to that source: https://github.com/sagemath/sage/blob/master/src/sage/combinat/vector_partition.py.  I swear I came up with this independently!

Answer (score -1):

Here is the simplest solution to your question:

```
def prime_factors(n):
    i = 2
    factors = []
    while i * i <= n:
        if n % i:
            i += 1
        else:
            n //= i
            factors.append(i)
    if n > 1:
        factors.append(n)
    return factors
```

Comment: No, it's not. I need divisor combinations (like those listed in the OP), not prime factors.

Comment: Sorry! Let me research on it!